# Trying to understand practical applications for bonded metal laminations & insulated epoxy coating

Tags: insulation

I am trying to better understand practical applications for bonded metal laminations and insulated epoxy coating. I started a new job at a company that does this and I am so lost. Any insight would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you [edit] to explain what you *do* know to avoid people wasting time explaining that?

Comment: Honest advice: the best experts on your topic are your colleagues, and "learning on the job" is kind of normal. How are we supposed to know the "practical applications" for what your company produces better than your colleagues?

Comment: Corrosion may exist anywhere metal exposed to moisture and so powder coated epoxy prevents this if done well. Hot zinc coating is done where the metal must conduct and may coated with Nickel

Comment: Thank you all, I am completely new to the electronics world, even the terms are foreign to me. I have done some research and find it too vague. My colleagues make bonded stacks and do insulated epoxy coating, but we never see what the end product is being used for. (Mainly aerospace and defense, I assume due to the confidentiality issues). I am new here and apologize if this is the wrong forum for my questions. Thank you kindly to those who have responded.

Answer (score 1):

Bonded metal laminations and insulated epoxy coating. Hmm. . . Sounds like your company makes transformers. Have you looked into the making of transformers. The process used for making these is very close to what you're describing. Look into it. It might help explain what you're looking to understand. Hope this helped.

Comment: Motors are another significant possibility.

Comment: Greatly appreciate your time and insight. Thank you!